Python regex and Gcode
I'm parsing Gcode files for 3D printing.  There are similar lines and I'm trying to pick the pattern (it indicates the function of the line).  One problem I've run into is returning a positive result whether or not a parameter is in the line.
These two lines are both extrusions (squirting plastic), but one has the "F" parameter in it.  The parameters will sometimes be integers, and other times they will be floats.  The X, Y, and E parameters may be negative or positive.
G1 F3000 X123.45 Y123.45 E123.45678
G1 X-200.00 Y200.00 E222.34567

This pattern kind of works, but fails for the second example where the "F" parameter is missing (which is most of the time).
G1 F(\d+\.\d+|\d+) X(-?\d+\.\d+|-?\d+) Y(-?\d+\.\d+|-?\d+) E(-?\d+\.\d+|-?\d+)

One problem looks to be that when the "F" parameter is missing, the pattern has an extra "space" character.  My workaround has been to use an IF statement, but it just looks clumsy.
I tried putting a "|" in hoping for "If F or not F" but haven't gotten that to work.
A second part of this would be; how do I return values from (for example) the "X" parameter?

A line of Gcode can contain any mixture of a couple dozen parameters, in any order whatsoever.  Regex is a completely inappropriate tool for the job.  Try an actual Gcode parser - https://pypi.org/project/gcodeparser/ for example.

If you are set on using regex, think about writing a function that individually grabs speciffic parts (one regex to match F (...). This will come with a lot more flexibility. As for a regex solution for this speciffic question try making the F part optional like so: G1 (?:F(\d+.\d+|\d+) )?X(-?\d+.\d+|-?\d+) Y(-?\d+.\d+|-?\d+) E(-?\d+.\d+|-?\d+). As for your "second part" consider asking a seperate question.

Regex
G1 +(X(?P<x>[^\s\r\n]+)[ ;]+)?(Y(?P<y>[^\s\r\n]+)[ ;]+)?(Z(?P<z>[^\s\r\n]+)[ ;]+)?(E(?P<e>[^\s\r\n]+)[ ;]+)?(F(?P<f>[^\s\r\n]+)[ ;]+)?

Explanation

(X(?P<x>[^\s\r\n]+)[ ;]+)?: optional named group x that matches the X coordinate.
[^\s\r\n]+: anything that is not a space (or any white character) or carriage return. This part could be improved to check it's 100% a number. But it was keep simple to keep the regex as light as possible.
[ ;]+ a space or a ;

Code example
Number are not converted to float in this example below.
import re

# Define the regular expression
regex = r"G1 +(X(?P<x>[^\s\r\n]+)[ ;]+)?(Y(?P<y>[^\s\r\n]+)[ ;]+)?(Z(?P<z>[^\s\r\n]+)[ ;]+)?(E(?P<e>[^\s\r\n]+)[ ;]+)?(F(?P<f>[^\s\r\n]+)[ ;]+)?"

# Initialize the list to store matches
matches_list = []

# Open and read the entire file content
with open('input.gcode', 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()

# Find all matches in the file content
matches = re.finditer(regex, content)

# Process each match
for match in matches:
    match_dict = match.groupdict()
    matches_list.append(match_dict)

# Display all named groups in one concatenated line for each match
for match in matches_list:
    print(f"X: {match['x']} Y: {match['y']} Z: {match['z']} E: {match['e']} F: {match['f']}")


# OTHER REPRESENTATION: Display all named groups for each match
# for match in matches_list:
#     # Print all named groups and their values
#     print("Match details:")
#     for group, value in match.items():
#         print(f"{group.upper()}: {value}")
#     print()  # Blank line for separation between matches

g-code File used to test
input.gcode
; START G-CODE
; Prusa 3D Printer - Example G-code for a 20x20x20mm cube
; Generated by Hand (Simplified Example)
; -------------------------------------

; Start-up routine
M104 S210 ; Set extruder temperature to 210°C (standby)
M140 S60  ; Set bed temperature to 60°C (standby)
M190 S60  ; Wait for bed to reach target temperature
M109 S210 ; Wait for extruder to reach target temperature

; Prime the extruder
G28       ; Home all axes
G92 E0    ; Reset extruder position
G1 Z0.2 F1200 ; Move nozzle to 0.2mm above bed
G1 X10 Y10 F1500 ; Move to starting point
G1 E10 F200 ; Extrude 10mm of filament to prime the nozzle

; Start the print
; Layer 1
G92 E0    ; Reset extruder position
G1 Z0.2 F1200 ; Set initial layer height
G1 X10 Y10 E0.5 F1200 ; Start first line
G1 X30 Y10 E1.5 F1200 ; Draw the first line
G1 X30 Y30 E1.5 F1200 ; Draw the second line
G1 X10 Y30 E1.5 F1200 ; Draw the third line
G1 X10 Y10 E1.5 F1200 ; Complete the first layer perimeter

; Layer 2
G92 E0    ; Reset extruder position
G1 Z0.4 F1200 ; Move up to the second layer
G1 X10 Y10 E0.5 F1200 ; Start second layer
G1 X30 Y10 E1.5 F1200 ; Draw the first line
G1 X30 Y30 E1.5 F1200 ; Draw the second line
G1 X10 Y30 E1.5 F1200 ; Draw the third line
G1 X10 Y10 E1.5 F1200 ; Complete the second layer perimeter

; Repeat layers to complete the cube
; (In a real G-code file, this would include commands for infill and more layers)

; End of the print
M104 S0   ; Turn off the extruder
M140 S0   ; Turn off the bed
G1 Z10    ; Move Z-axis up
G28 X0 Y0 ; Home X and Y axes
M84       ; Disable motors
; END G-CODE



@PM77-1, I've corrected. Thanks.

Thanks for the responses.  I had gone with the IF statements instead of the Regex.  It worked.  I had been hoping for a "catch-all" pattern that would pick out the different arrangements in a line.  I'm working within Cura so I have to live within it's capabilities.  The script works fine.  Thanks again to all. and a Happy Thanksgiving.

Ok I understand. In the past I had to deal with big gcode files. And iterating them line by line in python checking conditions was long.
If I were you would double check using the regex to catch groups, then again but with a regex that just get the instructions containing G1 like ^G1.*?[;\n] and write into a log file every times a match is appearing only using the second regex. This way you can keep an eye on the performance of your extraction.
Happy Thanksgiving too.

This particular script checks the total length of all the consecutive G0 travel lines and adds z-hops if they are > in total length so yes it's pretty slow.  It's for pellet feeders because they cannot retract.
